# How can I use gtk+ version 3.24 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, gtk3

I have tried to run a simple python program with GTK+3. However while executing, it throws the below error message "Required gtk+ version 3.24, current version is 3.18 (7)".. I hope for windows we do not have GTK+ 3.24 version yet, so what can be the alternative ?

main.py

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        gladeFile    = "main.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
        button       = self.builder.get_object("button")
        button.connect("clicked", self.printText)
        
    def printText(self, widget):
         print("Hello World!")
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    gtk.main()
```

Execution:

```
prompt  0:56:27.33>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main = Main()
  File "main.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
GLib.Error: gtk-builder-error-quark: main.glade:5:1 Required gtk+ version 3.24, current version is 3.18 (7)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just install the latest GTK version?

Comment: I hope, we don't have latest GTK version available for Windows 10.. I have searched but couldn't find the source.